# How to execute methods after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception

How to execute the add() method in the program below

```
class ExceptionHandlingImpl
{
  static void divide()
   {
      try
      {
        double a= 1/0;
      }
      catch(Exception e)
       {     
         throw e;        
       }
   }

  static void  add()
    {
      int a=20,b=30,c;
      c=ab+b;
      System.out.println(c);
    }

 public static void main(String args[])
  {
    divide();
    add();
  }

}
```

Why does the method add() doesn't execute when I give throw statement in the divide() method. The add() method execute fine when throw is commented.Is there anyway such that the exception is also thrown using throw and the method succeeding it also gets executed.

Comment: If you are throwing the exception, there is no point in even having that line of code in try-catch blocks to begin with.

Comment: Just replace the `throw` statement with `add()`

Comment: Why would you expect add to execute when control never reaches it??

Comment: @HotLicks: I am new to Exception Handling, I tried here in this way. Now I got the answer from posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `throw` the exception, you are basically saying "I have no idea what to do". So the exception bubbles up until it reaches the last stack frame of your program, and if unhandled as in this case, halts the program at that point.

Comment: I got the right explanation here intsead of why's from all on the program given.

Answer (score 0):

because from the method 'divide' you are throwing an exception.  If you want to continue you will need to catch and **NOT** re-throw the Exception

Comment: Or not intentionally throw the exception in the first place.

Comment: @user2310289: Suppose the try throws an userdefined exception and we need to 'throw' the exception to check what is happening, in this case how to call the method add()?

Answer (score 0):

throw e; will throw an exception  and crash the program.

```
 public class test
    {
      static void divide()
       {
          try
          {
            double a= 1/0;
          }
          catch(Exception e)
           {     
            System.out.println(e);        
           }
       }

      static void  add()
        {
          int a=20,b=30,c;
          c=a+b;
          System.out.println(c);
        }

     public static void main(String args[])
      {
        divide();
        add();
      }

    }
```